# How to print several files at the same time using lpr?

Tags: shell, printing

I am trying to print a number of files from shell using lpr. I enter something like:

```
lpr -P PRINTERNAME ./*/dir/file.pdf
```

but I get "lpr: No file in print request.".

When I use ls as

```
ls ./*/dir/file.pdf
```

it correctly lists the files I want to print.
Can someone help me understand what is going on?

Comment: Does your command work when you specify the path to just one file?

Comment: yes, it works when I give it a single file. I got around the issue by using a shell script: `for x in \`ls ./*/dir/file.pdf\`; do lpr -P PRINTERNAME $x; done`. Still I feel that the wildchars should have worked.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you came up with this workaround before I posted my answer.  Either will work...

Answer (score 4):

One of the ways I get the message

> lpr: No file in print request.

is when first file by pattern is an empty file.

E.g.:

```
$ touch f0
$ echo A > f1
$ lpr f*
lpr: No file in print request.
```

---

For you `for` alternative - you do not need `ls`; actually it is prone for bad
errors, e.g. if filenames contain spaces.

As an alternative you could try:

```
shopt -s nullglob  # So that if there are no matches you won't try to send
                   # pattern to printer.
for x in ./*/dir/file.pdf; do 
     lpr -P PRINTERNAME "$x"; 
done
shopt -u nullglob  # Restore
```

And remember to QUOTE. Always quote.

---

### Also note:

By using `lpr PATTERN` all files get queued to *one* job named as first
file in list.

That is:

```
# List files:
ls file*
file1 file2 file3

# Add to print job
lpr file*
```

Now file1 file2 and file3 should be in print queue – but not as three jobs,
but one. Name of the job is given from the first file if not set by option:

```
lpq
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)              Total Size
1st     user    80      file1                9248 bytes
                         |
                         +----- Actually is file1, file2, file3
```

If you have `lp` this is reported more verbosely by:

```
lp file*
request id is PRINTER-362 (3 file(s))
```

If you want you can also set a name for the job by e.g.:

```
lpr -T "My 3 Files" file*

lpq
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)              Total Size
1st     user    80      My 3 Files           9248 bytes
```

Comment: If you use zsh instead of bash you youse `setopt nullglob` and `unsetopt nullglob` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the details of the layout of your directories, I would guess that it's having trouble interpreting the different levels of subdirectories or perhaps spaces in file names.

You can try using `find` and piping the files to `lpr` with `xargs`:

```
find . -wholename "*/dir/file.pdf" -print0 | xargs -0 lpr -P PRINTERNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find /home/.../.../** -exec lp {} \;
```